# Mock Spring Security unit testing WebTestClient

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-security, spring-webflux, webtestclient

I am trying to write unit test cases for Mycontroller using **WebTestClient** in my web-flux Spring boot application.

It is always returning **401** while try to execute my unit test case. I already go through some old answers of stackoverflow but no luck.

Below are the approaches that I followed till now:

1. Disable security using @WebFluxTest(controllers = MyController.class,excludeAutoConfiguration = {ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class}))

   Above one disabled security perfecty but the issue is I am getting **java.security.Principal** ***null*** in MyController and controller throwing null pointer exception while trying to fetch value from Principal.
2. Add default bearer token in my webTestClient test. In this case I am getting 401.
3. Add valid bearer token in WebTestClient test that we are using to hit APIs normally. It this case as well I am getting 401[unauthorized] error.
4. Tried to mock Principal object but didn't got success. below is the code that I tried:

   ```
   Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);
   SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
   Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
   SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
   SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL);
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
   Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
   UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken principal1 = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("testUser", "testPass");

   Mockito.when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn(principal1);
   ```

Below is MyController and MyControllerTest class for your reference:

1. MyColroller.java

   ```
   @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, value = "/myController/{transactionId}")
   @Operation(
       security = @SecurityRequirement(name = OAUTH2),
       responses = {
               @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
                       content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                               schema = @Schema(implementation = TransactionDocumentResponse.class)))
       })
   public ResponseEntity<TransactionDocumentResponse> get(
       @PathVariable(value = "transactionId") String transactionId, Principal principal) {

       Map<String, String> userInfo = (Map) ((Authentication) principal).getDetails();
       utility.checkForMissingToken(userInfo, xTestHeader);
       return service.get(transactionId, userInfo);
   }
   ```
2. MyControllerTest.java

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @WebFluxTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
   @AutoConfigureWebTestClient
   @TestPropertySource(
           properties = {
                   "default-jwt-token = my default jwt token",
           }
   )
   public class MyControllerTests {

       private static final String testTransactionId = "abc_def";
       private static final BigInteger testTransactionIdBigInteger = BigInteger.valueOf(123);

       @Value("${default-jwt-token}")
       private String jwtToken;

       @MockBean
       MyServiceImpl service;

       @MockBean
       Utility utility;

       @Autowired
       private WebTestClient webTestClient;

       @Test
       public void test_success() {

           TransactionDocumentResponse transactionDocumentResponse = new TransactionDocumentResponse();
           transactionDocumentResponse.setTransactionId(testTransactionIdBigInteger);
           ResponseEntity<TransactionDocumentResponse> response = ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(transactionDocumentResponse));

           Mockito.doNothing().when(utility).checkForMissingToken(anyMap(), anyString());
           when(service.getRevolvingTransactions(anyString(), anyMap())).thenAnswer(createAnswer(response));

           WebTestClient.BodySpec<JSONObject, ?> stringBodySpec = webTestClient
                   .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                   .uri("/myController/{transactionId}", testTransactionId)
                   .headers(h -> {
                       h.setBearerAuth(jwtToken);
                   })
           .exchange()
           .expectBody(JSONObject.class);

           assertEquals(123, stringBodySpec.returnResult().getResponseBody().get("transactionId"));
       }
   }
   ```

Basically I need some mechanism to mock Spring security so that 401 error gone and I got some value in my Principal object.

Also I already tried older solutions so please don't mark it duplicate :).

Thanks

Comment: Spring Security provides integration with `WebTestClient`.  Check https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/test-webflux.html for details

Comment: As I can check on google. We can use WebTestCilent as a replacement of MockMvc to perform unit testing on web Flux Controller. 
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-webflux/webfluxtest-with-webtestclient/
Also as shared docs mentioned : "Spring Security provides integration with WebTestClient". I think it only means spring provide support for WebTestClient.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html

`@WithMockUser` and related annotations might be useful here and you won't need to do ugly mocking security context stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom annotation to mock Spring security part for my unit test cases because I need some extra fields while fetching value from Principal object in my controller.

Below is the code:

1. Create an annotation with name WithMockCustomUser

   ```
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)
   public @interface WithMockCustomUser {}
   ```
2. Annotation implementation part:

   ```
   public class WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory
   implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithMockCustomUser> {

   @Override
   public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithMockCustomUser customUser) {
       SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

       CustomUserDetails customUserDetails = new CustomUserDetails();

       AbstractAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(customUserDetails.getPrincipal(),
           customUserDetails.getCredentials(), customUserDetails.getAuthorities());

       auth.setDetails(customUserDetails.getDetails());

       context.setAuthentication(auth);
       return context;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create CustomUserDetails class that override Authentication class also override all abstract methods of Authntication and provide my custom implementation:

   ```
   public class CustomUserDetails implements Authentication {
       //Override Authentication class methods and return some cutstom values
   }
   ```

Hurray, Now my Custom annotation **@MockWithCustomUser** is ready to use with my unit test cases like below:

```
@Test
@MockWithCustomUser
public void myTest() {
   //Unit test code
}
```

Hope this help someone in mocking Spring Security with Custom implementation :)